# How to resolve the "Failed - Forbidden" error while creating and downloading a file in D3JS

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, download, tree

I have created a genealogy application based on Mike Bostock’s collapsible tree https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree.

I am trying to download the tree as an SVG document using the example http://bl.ocks.org/curran/7cf9967028259ea032e8
my code works if I use the static data in dataURL as is in the example

```
$('#download-SVG').click(function() {
    var dl = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(dl); // This line makes it work in Firefox.
    dl.setAttribute("href", dataURL);
    dl.setAttribute("download", "test.svg");
    dl.click();
   });
```

, however, if I use the modified code to use the SVG, I get a "Failed - Forbidden" error.

```
 $('#download-SVG').click(function() {
    var dl = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(dl); // This line makes it work in Firefox.
    dl.setAttribute("href", function (svg) {
     var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
     return "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
    });
    dl.setAttribute("download", "test.svg");
    dl.click();
   });
```

I would appreciate support in identifying the reason for this.

Comment: a) what's in the SVG b) what browser(s) give you forbidden?

Comment: @RobertLongson The SVG contains the tree (nodes and paths).  I am using Chrome.  I tried MS Edge and the error is "Couldn't download - No Permission".  I am running from localhost.

Comment: I saw the following error when investigated further:
You don't have permission to access /function (svg) { var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg); return "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML); } on this server.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to download the file by doing the following changes:

```
$('#download-SVG').click(function() {
    var dl = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(dl); // This line makes it work in Firefox.
    dl.setAttribute("href", svgDataURL(svg.node())); // pass the node
    dl.setAttribute("download", "test.svg");
    dl.click();
   });

 function svgDataURL(svg) {
     var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
     var dataURL = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
     return dataURL;
   }
```

The file downloads, but I am not able to open the file, which I suspect is due to the svg data content, but that is a different issue altogether.